# I have a list of data frames I would like to name individually by its own name.using the names function

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I was able to pull the files from a folder and have a list

```
#Set work directory
directory<-paste0("C://Program//User//Me//")

filestoread <- list.files(directory, pattern = "^LName_WWWF.*\\.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)


filelist = lapply(filestoread, function(x){as.data.frame(read_excel(x,sheet = 
                                                          "Sheet1"))})
```

The files names look  like this

```
"LName_WWWFRecvd2016_dated_20200204", "LName_WWWFRecvd2017_dated_20200204" , "LName_WWWFRecvd2018_dated_20200204", 
"LName_WWWFRecvd2019_dated_20200204","LName_WWWFRecvd2020_dated_20200204"
```

I would like to change them so that the names(filelist) function renames the file as

```
"WWWF2016", "WWWF2017" , "WWWF2018", 
"WWWF2019","WWWF2020"
```

I was thinking something as simple as removing everything before the first underscore and everything after then keeping concatenate left 4 and right 4. If you have a better idea by all means that is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sub`, we can capture the substring as a block and specify the backreference of the captured groups in `replacement`

```
names(filelist) <- sub("^[^_]+_([A-Z]+)R[a-z]+(\\d+)_.*",
       "\\1\\2", basename(filenm))

names(filelist)
#[1] "WWWF2016" "WWWF2017" "WWWF2018" "WWWF2019" "WWWF2020"
```

-details of pattern matching

```
`^` - start of the string
`[^_]+` - one or more characters not an underscore
`_` - followed by underscore
`([A-Z]+)` - capture one or more upper case letters
`R` - followed by letter R
`[a-z]+` - one or more lower case letters
`(\\d+)` - capture one or more digits
`_.*` - followed by underscore and rest of the characters
```

replacement

```
`\\1`-  backreference for first captured group
`\\2` - backreference for second captured group
```

#### data

```
filenm <- c("LName_WWWFRecvd2016_dated_20200204",    
     "LName_WWWFRecvd2017_dated_20200204", 
    "LName_WWWFRecvd2018_dated_20200204",       
    "LName_WWWFRecvd2019_dated_20200204", 
    "LName_WWWFRecvd2020_dated_20200204")
```

Comment: do you know why my files are being read in the whole file path? my results end up C://Program//User//Me//LName_WWWFRecvd2017_dated_20200204. do i cut string name directory?

Comment: @user35131 i thought you already stripped of the path.  You can use `basename(filenm)`.  Try the updated code

Comment: First time seeing how its done. Thank you. Everything worked perfect. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hope the code below works for you (thank @akrun's data)

```
> sub(".*_(\\w{4})\\w+(\\d{4})_.*", "\\1\\2", filenm)
[1] "WWWF2016" "WWWF2017" "WWWF2018" "WWWF2019" "WWWF2020"
```